# How to get location's address in not coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, api

I have been looking at some APIs and I found a weather API that suits my need but it accepts only location not coordinates or so I think. This is the API = [Api Doc's](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/conditions&MR=1). I did some reserch on getting location address based on coordinates but I have failed. I did come across this API by Microsoft but I got confused in the way they describe [the response](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx).

Comment: Location as in address?

Comment: don't use city name for rest. Underground weather accepts lat lng.

Comment: i check whether API URL. Go to bottom and check the response, its return the lat and long and also give address.

Comment: yes i need location as in adress like city and state is there an api for that

Comment: if underground weather accepts lat and long please tell me how to pass it in the url

Comment: https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=autocomplete-api

Comment: http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_Key/geolookup/q/37.776289,-122.395234.json

Comment: @KhawarIslam dude thanks man you are the best this is what i way looking for

Comment: Welcome Man.......

Comment: @KhawarIslam one more thing how do i get the weather for the cordinets like it just gives you info right i also need weather if you can help me her that will be apreciated

Comment: Please wait i am working on it

Comment: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139

Comment: in whcih you give the lat and long, in response you see the temperature fields

Comment: wait yah i figered it out you also need /conditions/ in the call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a "reverse geocode" lookup and is in the Core Location API.

```
func reverseGeocodeLocation(_ location: CLLocation, 
      completionHandler: @escaping CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

> This method submits the specified location data to the geocoding
>   server asynchronously and returns. When the request completes, the
>   geocoder executes the provided completion handler on the main thread.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder

Answer (score 0):

**API documentation and API weather give you aa location address as well as latitude and longitude also. Please see the images.**

[image: Image 1]

Response image after click on button.
[image]

Comment: yes i see this but i have the latitude and longitude and i want the adress like the city and state not the latitude and longitude which i already have